# As Apple is not providing webview in tvOS native development so with the use of TVML or TVJS can we open any web page or link

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, xcode7.1, tvjs

As I am working on a app that requires payment options like paypal or CashU, So Can we open these payment web pages using TVML or TVJS ? , IF yes then in which container as HTML provides iFrame tag.
       Does TVML or TVJS have any tag for the same.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no HTML rendering engine available so any payments (or similar) need to be made available and accessed by web services.